# For a JQuery App with several buttons, should I use <input> buttons, <a> buttons, <button> buttons, or something else?

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, button

I need to create a jQuery App with 30 buttons, from 1 to 30, whereby each one calls the exact same action script via Ajax where the parameter that is passed to the action script is simply the number of the button pressed (1 to 30).

For example, let's say the action script is `process.php`, if button 3 is pressed, then I need to pull data from `process.php?btn=3`, and if button 27 is pressed, then I need to pull data from `process.php?btn=27`.

Which type of button should I use for this: `<input>` buttons, `<a>` buttons, `<button>` buttons, or something else?  And why do you suggest that?

Also, how would Ajax get the corresponding value (1-30) of the button pressed with the method you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `<a/>` that way if JavaScript is disabled you can maintain the application's functionality.

```
<a href="process.php?btn=3" class="actionButton">Button 3</a>
```

And the script would simply use the `href` to post to your page.

```
$("a.actionButton").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post(this.href, {}, function(data){
    //do something with the data.
  });
});
```

**Update**

Since JavaScript is required than my recommendation would depend on your application design.  If you want the big buttons to look like buttons simply use `<input type="button" value="3"/>`  As by default they will have hover effect, depressed effect built out of the box.

If your buttons do not look like normal buttons maybe just blocks or some other style a `<div/>` could also be an option.  The one downside to using an `<a/>` would be you always have to suppress the default behavior of the `click()`

Comment: If Javascript is disabled, then the App should not work because I need to send other data via Ajax, not just the button that was pressed.  So considering that, and the fact that I do not need to create image buttons, do you still suggest using < a > buttons?  If so, why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each will work fine. But the `<a>` you can style with an image while `<input>` and `<button>` you cannot (the browser decides on the look).

Simply bind the click event on the button. Assuming you have this HTML:

`<a href="/process?button=1">Button 1</a>`

`<a href="/process?button=2">Button 2</a>`

`...`

`<a href="/process?button=3">Button 3</a>`

Here's the Javascript. The trick is to call the AJAX here, and return false to prevent the Browser from changing page.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(result) {
        alert('AJAX result = '+result);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't need to create image buttons, but I do need to create relatively BIG buttons, and I'm having difficulty doing that via CSS with < a > buttons.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: What difficulty are you having specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom attribute on each button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="YourCallbackMethod(this)" buttonNumber="1" value="Button 1" />
```

In your javascript

```
function YourCallbackMethod(button)
{
var number = $(button).attr("buttonNumber");

// Call the ajax method with the number value.
}
```

By doing this you can add additional attributes to extend the data stored in each button and it also makes chaning the AJAX target link very easy since it's centralised, rather than spread around multiple anchor tags.

Comment: But isn't one of the main benefits of JQuery/Ajax that you do not have to modify the HTML to implement dynamic code (the so-called separation of form and function)?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Marks answer, you could use a `<form>` element, and have each button a `submit` button; either a `input` or  `button`. Set the name of the element to "btn" and the value of the element to the button number.

```
<form id="foo" action="process.php" method="<!-- POST or GET? -->">
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="1">Button 1</button>
</form>
```

The jQuery would look something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#foo').bind('submit', function (evt) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                // whatever
            }
        });

        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If you want the submission to be a POST request, this would most likely be better. For a GET request however, Marks will probably be easier.

Comment: Are < button > tags treated the same by all browsers?  I've read that IE treats them differently.